# error: 'analogRead' was not declared in this scope

Tags: analogread

I am using Codeblocks with arduino IDE to simulate the control of a stepper motor, and the errors "'analogRead' was not declared in this scope" and "'A0' was not declared in this scope" keep popping. The code follows:

```cpp
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);
int stepCount = 0;  // number of steps the motor has taken

void setup() {
}

void loop()
{
    int sensorReading = analogRead(A0); //ERROR

    int motorSpeed = map(sensorReading, 0, 1023, 0, 100);

    if (motorSpeed > 0)
    {
        myStepper.setSpeed(motorSpeed);
        myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution / 100);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention it clear, but I do not own a board, that's why I'm trying to simulate it on PC.

Comment: Did you follow the rest of the process to integrate the Arduino environment into Codeblocks?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Do you have a link to this process?

Comment: did you try to include "Arduino.h"?

Comment: Did you get this issue fixed? If so, could you post an answer as to how you fixed it?

Comment: Also, which version of codeblocks?

Answer (score -1):

// yours code looks Ok, but i think problem is with Arduio IDE setting. Go to the "Tool > Boards...." in arduino IDE and make it sure that you have selected the right option of Arduino module. Mean it is same as you are using in hardware?

Comment: He is using Codeblocks IDE with Arduino core, not the actual Arduino IDE.